# how to print user selected part of a page in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

How to select the part of a page using javascript and print that chosen part in javascript.

Can you give some suggestions for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159223/how-to-print-selected-portion-of-html-page

Comment: Who is selecting and what? In the header you say "user selected", in the text you're asking, how to select with JS ...

Comment: @Teemu Ya i need that.. How to select the part of page using the javascript. Like screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *print style sheet* defining a class that hides things.  When the user chooses what to print, add that class to everything except what they want to print.

The stylesheet might look like this:

```
@media print {
    .dont-print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Then, say your page is made up of `div` sections with class `item`:

```
<div class="item">
...
</div>
<div class="item">
...
</div>
<div class="item">
...
</div>
```

When the user chooses an item to print, mark the *other* items with `dont-print`:

```
function printJustThis(div) {
    $(".item").not(div).addClass("dont-print");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But here how to select that region in your page.

Comment: @mani: Any way you like, that's far too broad a question. For instance, maybe each item contains a button saying "print just this". Then you'd have `$("selector for the button").on("click", function() { $(".item").removeClass("dont-print").not($(this).closest(".item")).addClass("dont-print"); });`

Comment: here user select the page by mouse.I don't know how to do that.. Can u suggest me to achieve this.